# Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/re8vdadt/) demonstrating my issue.

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var b = document.getElementById("b");

function A() {
    this.f = "1";
}

A.prototype.t = function() {
    b.innerHTML = this.f;
};

var a = new A();

var l = a.t;
l();
```

Why is `this` undefined when I try to call a.t? How do I recover that context without being overly verbose or storing too much?

Comment: Related: [What does this JavaScript syntax mean? `(0, _parseKey2.default)(something)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35522560/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is this undefined when I try to call a.t?

Because in JavaScript, `this` is set primarily by *how the function is called*, not where it's defined. `a.t()` sets `this` to `a` within the call, but `l()` sets `this` either to `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object (in loose mode).

More *(on my blog)*:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

The only exceptions are "bound" functions (as with `Function#bind`) or ES6's "arrow" functions (which get their `this` from the context in which they're defined).

> How do I recover that context without being overly verbose or storing too much?

[`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) is usually a good answer:

```
var l = a.t.bind(a);
l();
```

It returns a new function that, when called, calls the original with `this` set to the first argument you gave `bind`. (You can also bind other arguments.) It's an ES5 function, but if you need to support really old browsers, you can easily polyfill it.

---

If you just need to **call** `l` with a specific `this` value, and not always have it use that value, as [Robert Rossmann points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/javascript-losing-this-context-when-passing-around-members/30486415?noredirect=1#comment49051479_30486415) you can use `Function#call` or `Function#apply`:

```
l.call(this, 'a', 'b', 'c');    // Calls `l` with `this` set to `a` and args 'a', 'b', and 'c'
l.apply(this, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // Calls `l` with `this` set to `a` and args 'a', 'b', and 'c' -- note they're specified in an array
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) if the function does not need to be passed around and only needs to be called once: `var l = a.t; l.call(a);`

Comment: Concerning the original asker's code, would it be valid if `A.t()` was defined within the original `A` function? This way the function would be able to access a privately-scoped variable ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/re8vdadt/1/)).

Comment: @RobertRossmann could you demonstrate that?

Comment: @eatonphil: `l.call(a)` will call `l` with `this` set to `a`.

Comment: @JeffNoel: Yes. It wouldn't be `this`, but yes. It *might* be "retaining too much," however.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is functionally scoped,

To execute a function with the right value for this, you will need to bind it to the right object. For example,

```
var l= a.t.bind(a);
```

Comment: But binding context isn’t really related to scope.

Answer (score 1):

Because the context changes when you assign the function to a new variable. You could always just do `a.t();`.