# What does this JavaScript syntax mean? (0, _parseKey2.default)(something)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I find this notation everywhere in Webpack generated libs but I don't understand it :

```
var a = (0, _parseKey2.default)(something)
```

What does the `(0, _parseKey2.default)` stands for? I don't remember seeing those comma separated expressions between parenthesis elsewhere that in function parameters, so maybe I am just missing something simple.

Comment: This is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). No clue though why webpack is generating stuff like this, but I have seen that, too.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is to give `_parseKey2.default` the correct `this` (or, rather, no `this` at all), that is, to call it as an ordinary function, not a method. Consider:

```
var p = {
    f : function() {
        console.log(this)
    },
    x : "foo"
};

p.f();      // { f: ... x: foo }
(p.f)();    // { f: ... x: foo }
(0, p.f)(); // implicit global this
```

The comma expression is a more concise way to do this:

```
 var unbound = p.f;
 unbound();
```

Comment: More in [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/references.html).