# Navigate from within Promise callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am just starting out with React Native and am running into the following problem when trying to navigate from within a Promise callback.

Here is the following code I am trying to run. I want to navigate to another screen if the http request returns that the user's login information is correct.

```
login() {
  axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${Globals.WebAPI}/api/authentication/login`,
      data: {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }
  })
  .then(function(response) { 
      console.log(response.data.token)
      AsyncStorage.setItem("AuthToken", response.data.token);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('PictureDetails', {base64: photo.base64});
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
}



render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    <Button
      title="Go to Details"
      onPress={this.goToDetails}
    />
    <Button
      title="Signup"
      onPress={this.goToSignup}
    />
    <Text>Username</Text>
    <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
    value={this.state.username}
  />
  <Text>Password</Text>
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
    value={this.state.password}
  />
  <Button
      title="Login"
      onPress={this.login}
    />
  </View>
)};
```

This is the error that I am getting from this function:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')
```

I feel like this error is coming from me not fully understanding the props usage, so I am hoping that this answer helps solidify my knowledge of what's going on in React Native.

Thanks in advance

Comment: here `.then(function(response) { 
      console.log(response.data.token)
      AsyncStorage.setItem("AuthToken", response.data.token);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('PictureDetails', {base64: photo.base64});
  })` your `this` pointer to class instance is lost. So you can bind the `this` with arrow function.

Comment: For more information on what @KarenGrigoryan is describing, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/losing-this-context-in-javascript-when-passing-around-members. To elaborate on the solution: `onPress={this.login.bind(this)}` or `onPress={x=> this.login()}` either of these methods should work.

Comment: @SamMallabone instead of `then(function(response) { ...` use arrow function `then((response) => {...`

Comment: Ah, @KarenGrigoryan and I were actually talking about two different issues. She is pointing out that the function `this` will obscure the class level `this`. I believe you will also need to bind the class `this` in your `onPress` event.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan that works perfectly, thanks! If you want to convert that to an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Great, sure I will shortly, thanks

Comment: @David784 I actually already bound the function to this in the constructor. The scoping of the this function was the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part loses `this` binding:

```
  .then(function(response) { 
      console.log(response.data.token)
      AsyncStorage.setItem("AuthToken", response.data.token);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('PictureDetails', {base64: photo.base64});
  })
```

so when you call `this.props.navigation.navigate(`, `this` is `undefined`, which is what your error tells you.

The easiest fix is to convert regular function to an arrow function, which lexically binds the `this` to surrounding context's `this` value.

```
  .then((response) => { 
      console.log(response.data.token)
      AsyncStorage.setItem("AuthToken", response.data.token);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('PictureDetails', {base64: photo.base64});
  })
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions)

Answer (score -3):

I guess you didn't create a Navigation object using react-navigation library.
I need to see the whole file of this code to make sure what the reason is.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It better you seek clarification in comments rather than as a reply. Then when all is clear, post a reply.