# Please explain the behavior in the below picture

Tags: javascript

[image: Can Some one explain why highlighted section is coming as undefined**strong text**]

Can some one explain this behavior

Comment: Kindly post your code not image, refer to this [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/losing-this-context-in-javascript-when-passing-around-members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the behavior of the "**this**" keyword on the different contexts where it's been used.

> So here is the complete reference for **this** keyword
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
var foo = {  
    bar : function(){ 
            console.log(this); // For your reference
            return this.baz;  
          },
    baz: 1
};

(function(v){
    console.log(typeof arguments[0]()); // In this context "this" keyword refers to the current function "bar" and not the parent foo object, As the current function doesn't contain baz it returns undefined
    console.log(typeof foo.bar());  // In this context "this" keyword refers to its parent "foo" Object so this.baz will be refer to foo.baz and typeof 1 is a number
    console.log(typeof v()); // Here "this" keyword refers to the window object hence this.baz will refer to window.baz which is undefined
    return typeof arguments[0]();
})(foo.bar);
```