# Event Listener for Ag-grid cell in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, addeventlistener, ag-grid-angular

I am using `Ag-grid` in `Angular 9` as per [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project).

So it is a very basic grid populated with some car model and car price.

The parent component where this code is written is **`app component`**. Now i wanted to edit details of any car ( example: price ) in another component ( **`edit-car-details`** ).

The problem is when i am *rendering the cell of ag-grid by adding a click event listener* to it, their is a variable ( `editClicked` ) defined in `App component` which i am unable to *access* in the listener.

**`Summary of the question`** : **Is there a way to send data to child component from the event listener of a particular cell in parent component's grid?**

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EmbeddedViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular-latest-version';

  columnDefs = [
      { field: 'make' },
      { field: 'model' },
      { field: 'price' , cellRenderer: this.editCar}
  ];

  rowData = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
  ];

  editClicked : boolean = false;
  timeIndia;

  constructor(){
    this.timeIndia = moment.tz(moment(),'Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').valueOf();
  }

  editCar(params){
    var createDiv = document.createElement('div');
    createDiv.innerHTML = '<a style="font-weight:bold;">'+params.data.price+' <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
    createDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log('Inside listener');
      this.editClicked = true;                //<============ problem in this line  : ERROR in 
                                              // src/app/app.component.ts:37:12 - error TS2339: Property 
                                              //'editClicked' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'
    });

    return createDiv;
  }

}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<div style="margin-left: 2em;">
  Current time is ::
  <br>
  <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2em;">{{timeIndia}}</span>
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
  </ag-grid-angular>

  <app-edit-car-details *ngIf="editClicked"></app-edit-car-details>

</div>
```

`edit-car-details.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-car-details',
  templateUrl: './edit-car-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-car-details.component.css']
})
export class EditCarDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('inside edit component');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ field: 'price' , cellRenderer: this.editCar.bind(this)}
```

This works. Got idea from @yazan. It has got to do with binding the current context.

Comment: Anyone with a better solution is also welcomed. I am open to new approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the `current context using arrow function`:

```typescript
    createDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log('Inside listener');
          this.editClicked = true;                //<============ use arrow function
                                                  
        });
```

Another approach to bind the `current context and call a function`

```typescript
 createDiv.addEventListener('click',this.ClickElement.bind(this));

  ClickElement(){
      console.log('Inside listener');
      this.editClicked = true;  
  }
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64858212/4309639)

Comment: Sorry @yazan, your solution didn't work, but not entirely however , it did give me an insight on what to do. Thank you for that. Please see my solution and check whether it is fine or not.