# Combine arrays in map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I have an issue, or at least I'm not having the solution.

I'm getting some API calls via a map and I can console.log all results which is great, but the problem is that I want to combine all the results in one array.

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

alpha.map(alpha => {
 fetch(`https://myurl.com/api/members/page?prefix=${alpha}`)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => matches.push)
 .then(() => console.log(matches))
})
```

I guess I have to do some sort of await or something?

My response from the API looks like this:

```
{"list_complete":true,"keys":
    [
        {
            "username": "name.com",
            "uuid": "-47c9-88b6-2474090c7927",
            "user_type": 1,
            "subscribed": "false",
            "lastLogin": 1611066809086,
            "profile": {
                "name": "Name Lastname",
                "email": "name.com",
                "uuid": "3e92f458-6331-2-88b6-2474090c7927",
                "address": "",
                "history": [
                    {
                        "titleId": "5fac58f764e6710017411e79",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Guns N ´ Roses - Appetite for Democracy",
                        "t": 0,
                        "d": 8492.2
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5f7eadb3963c170017a919f3",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Frank Zappa - Apostrophe Overnite Sensation (Classic Albums)",
                        "t": 7.728575,
                        "d": 2974.9
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5e4463a395c832405e7effc0",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Bob Marley - Uprising Live!",
                        "t": 3285.406821,
                        "d": 6807.7
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5f80c6d0045fdf0017735019",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Van Morrison - In Concert",
                        "t": 3610.529879,
                        "d": 4558.29
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5fa85aba9c4a1900177e5cf9",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Iron Maiden - En Vivo!",
                        "t": 2522.988949,
                        "d": 3380.5
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5f719cb75d994e0017b429c5",
                        "posterUrl": "url.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Placebo - Placebo Live At The O2 Brixton Academy",
                        "t": 1426.589863,
                        "d": 5061.89
                    },
                    {
                        "titleId": "5fb3fd1731be640017c2f878",
                        "posterUrl": "https://slam-assets.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/staging/5fb3fd1731be640017c2f878/cover/1606214166013_nirvanastaende.jpg",
                        "displayName": "Nirvana - Nevermind (Classic Albums)",
                        "t": 0,
                        "d": 2948.69
                    }
                ],
                "favourites": [
                    "5f9039ed1279d600170378c2",
                    "5facf94364e6710017411e7d",
                    "5e4463a395c832405e7effc0"
                ]
            },
            "subscription": null
        }
    ]
}
```

And the data I want to collect is in a array called history under each user.

Comment: Look into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and related methods. How exactly do you plan to use the result values?

Comment: Cool. thank you. Will have a look. When I have all the data collected I will combine all users history into one.

Comment: If `matches` is an array, `matches.push` ain't gonna do much. You'd want `.then(matches.push)` if you want to push `data` into `matches` (or `then(data => { matches.push(data); })` so that you don't get a response of the new length of `matches` (the output of `push`).

Comment: See here for an example of using `Promise.all()`: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-wait-multiple-promises-javascript/

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know, you can’t edit the comment anymore, but just for the record, `.then(matches.push)` won’t work due to the [method context being lost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30486345/4642212); it’d need to be `.then(matches.push.bind(matches))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding you are getting `data` as a result of your fetch, and you will get as many returns of `data` for the elements of the `alpha` array. You would like to combine the results of your `history` object, from the data, into a single one-dimensional array. That means that your target array looks like:

```js
histories = [{},{},{} ... ]
```

Where each object `{}` is a history element.

In order to perform the required operation we need to access the `keys` elements first and iterate through all of those, retrieving the `history` contents from each of them. However, you mentioned `history` may or may not exist for a user, thus we need to check for its existance .

So, summing up:

- We need to iterate through all the element of `keys`
- We need to check if within the above elements, `history` exists before trying to do something with it.

We may perform the first action by using a `forEach()` method on `data.keys`, whilst a simple `if (element.profile.history)` to check for the presence of `history`:

```js
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const histories = [];

alpha.map(alpha => {
    fetch(`https://myurl.com/api/members/page?prefix=${alpha}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => data.keys.forEach(function (e) { //Iterate through the keys
            if (e.profile.history) { //If history is present
                histories.push(...e.profile.history); //Pushing to array with spread sytnax
            }
        })
        )
})
```

In order to have one single array with all the `history` items, we made use of the spread `...` syntax, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

So the output of:

```js
console.log(histories)
```

Will then yield:

```js
[
  {
    titleId: '5fac58f764e6710017411e79',
    posterUrl: 'url.jpg',
    displayName: 'Guns N ´ Roses - Appetite for Democracy',
    t: 0,
    d: 8492.2
  },
  {
    titleId: '5f7eadb3963c170017a919f3',
    posterUrl: 'url.jpg',
    displayName: 'Frank Zappa - Apostrophe Overnite Sensation (Classic Albums)',
    t: 7.728575,
    d: 2974.9
  },
  {
    titleId: '5e4463a395c832405e7effc0',
    posterUrl: 'url.jpg',
    displayName: 'Bob Marley - Uprising Live!',
    t: 3285.406821,
    d: 6807.7
  },
...
]
```

Comment: Such a big help. Lots of thanks again. Of course I up voted it and marked it as solved. Ive learned a lot and tested a lot. So im grateful. Yes, was what I was thinking also but cant access it outside when im trying to loop it it out.

Comment: No problem at all and thanks very much! Regarding this other problem: `histories` is actually accessible from outside the `map()` function, you can try yourself by performing something like `console.log(histories[0].titleId)` outside of the  map()` as this will print the titleId of the **first** history. Is this more or less what you are looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pushing them into an array?

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const results = [];

alpha.map(alpha => {
fetch(`https://myurl.com/api/members/page?prefix=${alpha}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => results.push(data))
})
```

Comment: Yes, then I get an array, but still in that array I have 5 different ones. Want to compile it down to one single array.

Comment: try changing:
then(data => results.push(data))
to:
.then(data => results.push(...data))

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using `alpha.map`, I would suggest `alpha.forEach`, as you are only looping there, not mapping.

You could use `await` instead of `.then`, but that's just the way you handle the `Promise` returned from `await`.

```
const urls = [/* your urls here */];
const matches = [];
urls.forEach( url => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  matches.push(json);
});
console.log(matches);
```

Using your existing style, push the `data` into the `matches` array, and log once you're done:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var matches = [];
alpha.forEach(alpha => {
 fetch(`https://myurl.com/api/members/page?prefix=${alpha}`)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => matches.push(data))
});
console.log(matches);
```

You could use `Promise.all` to run the `fetch` calls in parallel, but that's another story.

I think perhaps your JSON returned in an array, so you end up with an array of arrays? Take a look at [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), and use it to add the `res.json` to the `matches` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that using `Promise.all`, like this:

```
var alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var memberHistories = await Promise.all([...alpha.map(item => {
  return fetch(`https://myurl.com/api/members/page?prefix=${item}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.keys.filter((e) => e.profile.history).flatMap((e) => e.profile.history));
})]);

var allHistories = memberHistories.flat();
```

Note the use of `flatMap()` for merging multiple keys' histories then finally `flat()` for merging the history entries for all members.