# Why just passing pause method of audio object in addEventListener doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-audio

Let me say there is an audio object named `myAudio` which is playing music now on.
I wanted to make a button element which pauses the music when an user push it.
First, I implemented like this:

```
const btn = document.createElement("div");
btn.addEventListener("click",myAudio.pause); // caught an illegal invocation error.
```

I embed the pause method directly in the second argument of the `addEventListener`.
However, the browser returned illegal invocation error even if the `pause` method is surely defined in Audio object of HTML5.

Secondly, I tried to write pause method using arrow funciton:

```
const btn = document.createElement("div");
btn.addEventListener("click",() => myAudio.pause()); // it worked
```

And it worked.

I don't get why the first way is impossible.
Is it just my misunderstanding of a syntax of JavaScript or the problem that is specific of audio object?

### addition

I'm sorry I could not understand what of the suggested question is related with this question.
The suggested question is about `this`  keyword but I could not find `this` in my snippet above.
Is it that `this` keyword is used inside the `pause` method?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+method+loses+this+context+when+passed+as+parameter) of [Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30486345/4642212). You can still use `myAudio.pause.bind(myAudio)`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean `this` keyword is used inside the pause method and we need to explicitly bind it with `myAudio`?

Comment: Yes, implicitly. `Audio.prototype.pause` is implemented by the host environment, so there isn’t necessarily a literal `this` keyword; the important thing is that a _`this` context_ is used in that method.

Comment: I got it.  Thank you.