# Why doesn't work the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Store.DisplayBooks)

Tags: javascript

I follow some tutorials. So I write the code myself, then I watch the result. In the tutorial the DOMContentLoaded works, but when I try to call the function in this addeventlistener, then the code fails.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" />
    <style>
      .success,
      .error {
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
      }

      .success {
        background: green;
      }

      .error {
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Book List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Add Book</h1>
      <form id="book-form">
        <div>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" id="title" class="u-full-width" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="author">Author</label>
          <input type="text" id="author" class="u-full-width" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
          <input type="text" id="isbn" class="u-full-width" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="u-full-width" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <table class="u-full-width">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="book-list"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="appes6.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }
}

class UI {
  addBookToList(book) {
    const list = document.getElementById('book-list');

    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>${book.title}</td>
    <td>${book.author}</td>
    <td>${book.isbn}</td>
    <td><a href='#' class='delete'>X</a></td>
    `;
    list.appendChild(row);
  }

  showAlert(message, classname) {
    //create div
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = `alert ${classname}`;
    //add text
    div.textContent = message;
    //get parent
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const form = document.querySelector('#book-form');

    //insert alert
    container.insertBefore(div, form);

    //time out

    setTimeout(function () {
      div.remove();
    }, 2000);
  }

  clearFields() {
    document.getElementById('title').value = '';
    document.getElementById('author').value = '';
    document.getElementById('isbn').value = '';
  }
}
// local storage class
class Store {
  static getBooks() {
    let books;
    if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
    }
    return books;
  }
  static displayBooks() {
    const books = this.getBooks();
    let ui = new UI();
    books.forEach(function (book) {
      ui.addBookToList(book);
    });
  }

  static addBook(book) {
    let books = this.getBooks();
    books.push(book);
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  }
  static removeBook(book) {
    let books = this.getBooks();
    books.forEach((b) => console.log(b.title));
    books = books.filter((b) => b.title !== book);
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}

document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.className === 'delete') {
    e.target.closest('tr').remove();
    Store.removeBook(e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('td:first-child').textContent);

    const ui = new UI();
    ui.showAlert('Delete success', 'success');
  }
});

// event listener for add a book
document.getElementById('book-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //get form values
  const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
  const author = document.getElementById('author').value;
  const isbn = document.getElementById('isbn').value;
  //validate
  if (title === '' || author === '' || isbn === '') {
    //error alert
    ui.showAlert('Please fill in all fields', 'error');
    return;
  }

  //instantiate book
  const book = new Book(title, author, isbn);

  //instantiate UI list
  const ui = new UI();

  ui.addBookToList(book);

  // add to local storage
  Store.addBook(book);
  ui.showAlert('Successfully added a new book', 'success');
  ui.clearFields();
  //clear fields
});

Store.displayBooks();

// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Store.displayBooks);
```

If you comment out the second last code line, and remove the comment from the last code line, then the code give some error.

Comment: "Then the code give some error": what error?  Please edit the question to include the details of the error you are getting.  Please don't expect us to run your code just to figure out what the error is.

Comment: Please include the error code as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/losing-this-context-in-javascript-when-passing-around-members)

Answer (score 1):

in displayBooks method change `const books = This.getBooks();` with `const books = Store.getBooks();`

the problem is : 'this' reference document object there and there is no method in document name displayBooks

Comment: More to the point, `static` methods should not reference `this`; it defeats the point of being `static` as opposed to an instance method.