# Multiple uses of a function in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

If I use the first representation, the console will log the name, however in the second one it does output "JS Bin Output", any idea what happened?

```js
let person = {
  name: 'Fred',
  sayMyName: function(params) {
    return (this.name);
  },
};

let obj = person;
person = null;
let sayMyName = obj.sayMyName;
console.log(obj.sayMyName()); // logs `Fred`
console.log(sayMyName()); // logs `JS Bin Output`
```

Comment: Calling `sayMyName();` will log `window.name` (which appears to be some sort of uuid in StackOverflow snippets), not `undefined`. In strict mode, it will throw a `cannot access property name of undefined` exception. Try `let sayMyName = obj.sayMyName.bind(person);`

Comment: Please note the change in my code

Comment: For what reason are you nulling `person`?

Comment: wouldn’t I still get the same output if I removed that line?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking. What's your thought in assigning null there?

Comment: Commenting that line out didn't change the output unfortunately, I feel like I am missing something about the "this" value.

Comment: Check the links in the duplicate notification above your post, especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/losing-this-context-in-javascript-when-passing-around-members

Comment: @mka1 The `person = null;` line has nothing to do with the `this` behavior. The `this` behavior is explained in each of the linked posts. That issue should be solved. What we’re additionally asking _now_ is: why _did_ you put `person = null;` there? What did you hope this would achieve?